# Cant receive data to php variables from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

I've a function of Fullcalendar plugin which should insert in mysql bbdd some data which is transfered by ajax to php.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Evento a insertar:');
            if (title) {
                start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
                end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');

                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'http://localhost/test-fullcalendar/php/add_evento.php',
                     data: {"title": title, "start": start, "end": end},
                     type: "POST",
                     success: function(json) {
                        alert('OK');
                        console.log(title + ' ' + start + ' ' + end);
                     }
                 });
                 calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                 {
                     title: title,
                     start: start,
                     end: end,
                     allDay: allDay
                 },
                 true
                 );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        }
```

And my php receive it:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
```

The problem comes when php told me that variables are `"undefined index"`. I try putting behind an `isset()` but `echo` dont show anything so the insert to the mysql table dont runs correctly.

Whats the problem? I dont have experience with Ajax and I think it has relation with the `success function` because I read that there isn't a particular way to receive data in php from ajax, only the classic method POST..

Thanks

Comment: Try to change this backtick after "end" to single quote as well: `$end = $_POST['end\`];`

Comment: Are you getting "OK" alert? Try also alerting values of those variables just before ajax call, to see do they have correct values. And what's a meaning of those doubled stars? But, you can first change those $_POST to $_REQUEST and try calling your add_evento.php script directly, from browser bar, and place some dummy parameters there...to make sure is problem on PHP or JS side.

Comment: @MilanG Yes, i receive OK alert and console.log returns the correct value. The double stars is to bold that part in my question but it failed.. I try with $_REQUEST and again, accessing .php directly from browser bar: Undefined index to the 3 variables..

Comment: @AvkZ In your .php, have you tried : <?php print_r($_POST); ?> ?

Comment: @angellica.araujo it shows an empty array

Comment: @AvkZ Are you sure your title, start and end variables are correct set before sending the request? Don't you get any JavaScript error?

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax structure is correct, I think the problem is the data that you are posting to php script. Try to use `console.log(title + ' ' + start + ' ' + end);` **before** `$.ajax`. Probably one or more data is incorrect. One of the possible problem is `$.fullCalendar.moment().format()`. Probably this function does not return a simple string, therefore you can't use it in your ajax data. Try to use `console.log()` for "start", "end" and "title" separately.

Comment: It returns in correctly format which i want to insert in the table. `console.log `returns `title: testing start: 2015-03-10 12:00:00 end: 2015-03-11 12:00:00` My mysql table have start and end columns in `DATETIME` type

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the double quotes from the line where you pass data in the AJAX call, like this

```
data: {
title: title,
start: start, 
end: end
},
```

Comment: I change it now, by console.log in browser, it shows correctly the values like before but the .php dont receive it in the variables and say that every variable is `Undefined index`, moreover if I `echo print_r($_POST)` it shows an empty array :S. Why the data cant be received if im sending it correctly? i dont understand anything.

Comment: Ok, if you changed the double quotes already and it is still not working, I suggest to test further. Undefined index error is supposed to come if one of the post data variables is not set. So I suggest to manually hard code some values to the post data and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to debug a little bit more.

Navigate to your developers tools 'Network' tab and see what are you sending

[image: Network tab]

If everything you are sending is OK, then we can continue making some modifications to make the code comunicate more to you.
For example, we could start from the success callback:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Evento a insertar:');
            if (title) {
                start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
                end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
                console.log('Sending:', title, start, end);
                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'http://localhost/test-fullcalendar/php/add_evento.php',
                     data: {"title": title, "start": start, "end": end},
                     type: "POST",
                     success: function(json) {
                        var res = JSON.parse(json);
                        if(res.result === 'OK') {
                            alert('OK');
                        }
                        else {
                            console.error(res.message);
                        }

                     }
                 });
                 calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                 {
                     title: title,
                     start: start,
                     end: end,
                     allDay: allDay
                 },
                 true
                 );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        }
```

Now, in the PHP part:

```
<?php
//Check existance
if(!isset($_POST['title']) || !isset($_POST['start']) || !isset($_POST['end'])) {
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>'KO','message'=>'Invalid input! '.var_export($_POST, true)));
    exit;
}


//Check emptyness
if(empty($_POST['title']) || empty($_POST['start']) || empty($_POST['end'])) {
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>'KO','message'=>'Empty input! '.var_export($_POST, true)));
    exit;
}

//title, start and end exists in POST and are not empty

try {
//SQL code, insert/update blablabla
}
catch(Exception $e) {
   echo json_encode(array('result'=>'KO','message'=>$e->getMessage()));
   exit;
}
//....

//All went ok
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'OK'));
```

Now, with this code, you will be able to know what is happening to your php, and see the errors in the javascript console.

Comment: First step: Everything is sending OK to my .php, after that, I copy your code of success function to check it and dev tools told me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A` in the `index.html:1` which is my `<!DOCTYPE html>` . I dont understand the relation that it have with ajax.. And in the last step (in the php) it returns `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER)` in the two `exit 1` of each conditional. If i change the two exit 1 to only `exit`, php returns the first message of `Invalid input!`

Answer (score 0):

i have the answer for your problem, just change your start and end variable in your data to start.format() and end.format()